# Pattern matching for string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a help for pattern for float value.

String that i have:

```
[[-307.,16.01,-171.31],[0.84528,-0.503623,-0.142485,-0.107531],[-1,-2,1,1],[9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09]], [[-306.43,24.47,-176],[0.845282,-0.503624,-0.142472,-0.107528],[-1,-2,1,1],[9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09,9E+09]]
```

Pattern that I'm using:

```
\s*[-+]?([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\s*
```

What changes that I have to do in my pattern such that I'm able to recognise whole text. Right now problem with
[306.43,24.47,-176] this which is part of this long string.
what changes I have to do with this pattern.

Comment: Here is a [very good link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) for regexp "cookbook-style" examples. The one you need is this: `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`

Comment: Do you have to use Regex? Can't you just split on the comma and use double.Parse?

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex. You can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var list = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                .Deserialize<List<List<List<Double>>>>("[" + yourstr + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a + or * for the decimal places:

```
\s*[-+]?([0-9].)?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\s*
```

Comment: I have used this pattern \s*[-+]?([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\s* Pls have a look.tell me this right pattern for my string what i want to recongise.